# Make certain pixel colors (or ranges) in an Android FrameLayout or View transparent

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity `View` within a `FrameLayout` like this:

```
View unityView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
myFrameLayout.addView(unityView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Is there a way to apply a filter to the view or framelayout to make certain pixels (based on their color/hue/saturation/lightness) transparent so that whatever is underneath the `FrameLayout` can be seen?

---

Update:

I (think I) am able to get the `UnityPlayer`'s underlying `SurfaceView` by doing the following:

```
Field f = view.getClass().getDeclaredField("i"); //NoSuchFieldException
f.setAccessible(true);
SurfaceView sf = (SurfaceView) f.get(view); //IllegalAccessException
SurfaceHolder sfhTrackHolder = sf.getHolder();
sfhTrackHolder.addCallback(myHolderCallback);
```

In myHolderCallback I've got:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Canvas canvas = null;
    try {
        canvas = holder.lockCanvas(null);
        if(canvas != null){
            synchronized (holder) {
                // TODO: stuff here
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (canvas != null) {
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

But this crashes the app on the `holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);` line with error `[EGL] Failed to create window surface: EGL_BAD_ALLOC: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.`.

The SurfaceView must have been private for good reason.

So: I still don't know how to do this.